# Joining tables using different data types (Optimized)

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sqldatatypes

I have a View created where I can see the overall life of a product. I would like to add another table that gives me additional information.
The problem I have is that the table I want to join has a different data type PK.
Converting the data type at the join level will cause performance issues.

Is there a way I can write the query differently so that it avoids avoid full table scan in my SQL join process?

a.Productid - Data type is varchar
b.ProductID - Data Type is bigint

```
Select a.productid,
 a.Productname, 
 a.location,
 a.date,
 b.loanamount
from viewtable a 
 left join table b 
 on a.productid = convert(varchar(10),b.productid)
```

Time of execution before the join is 3 minutes. time after join and conversions is 6 minutes. I'd like to keep it close to the 3 minute execution time.

Comment: Can you add execution plan? Otherwise it's going to be difficult to help you.

Comment: Is `b.productId` an `nvarchar` field? If so, it is better to change the data type on b (unless you actually need `nvarchar` data there, but for some reason `viewtable` doesn't). The [varchar key] vs [nvarchar match] is a known slowdown, and the best solution is to convert the `nvarchar` field into a `varchar` field.

Comment: Try creating a computed column on one of the tables that converts the value to the datatype of the other and then join on that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What @Isaac said And don't forget to INDEX that column, with any appropriate INCLUDE columns.

Comment: @Isaac and pmbAustin Thank you for your help!! Definitely glad i asked this question

Comment: b/c im lazy i wouldve been tempted to dump table b into temp tbl doing the conversion then, indexing it, then doing the join

Comment: If you've done the obvious (indexed the join predicates) and you have to convert b.productid, probably the only way to speed it up is to make the tables smaller or get  faster hardware.  FWIW it bothers me that you have two tables with the same column names and (apparently) the same meaning, but the data types differ.  Try making your tables conformant and ditch the convert function call